# What does 'do' mean in 'The sweetest dream will never do'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

I can't comprehend what a singer/writer means singing this song.  Would anyone explain 'Do' for what thing used?

For example:

> Cause even when I dream of you
>   The sweetest dream will never **do**
>   I'd still miss you baby
>   And I don't want to miss a thing

Comment: **do** can mean "suffice"

Comment: what was Do used instead? or does singer mean, "Even when I dream of you the sweetest dream will never dream

Comment: The sweetest dream will never *suffice*.  That is, the dream, no matter how sweet it may be, will never be the same as having you here beside me.

Answer (score 2):

"Do" here means "be enough". so you can translate the lyrics as :

*Cause even when I dream of you, the sweetest dream will never be enough*

the reason "do" was used here is so that the lyrics would rhyme.

Answer (score 0):

"Do" means it won't be enough; in your dreams you can get the impossible; the sweetest dream would be a dream where you get everything you want; but just dreaming it will never be enough for them because it's just a dream you'll wake up from and it'll be done with; so even the sweetest dream won't be enough because you want it in reality.